# Saving entity with one to many relationship overwrites database changes or related entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I've created an entity DownloadDroplet with a ManyToOne reference to Process

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "process_id")
private Process process;
```

And process with a one to many reference to DownloadDroplet

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "process", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DownloadDroplet> downDrops;
```

I have code that gets DownloadDroplets from the **dropletRepo** and eventually saves and flushes updates to the database that I visually confirm are updated in the database

```
Set<DownloadDroplet> aDownDropSetCompleted = dropletRepo.findByStatusAndRunDateAndType(DropletStatus.COMPLETED, runDateAsDate, FBTDropletType.SETDOWNLOADER);
```

...

I then save the status of the process

```
 setProcess.setStatus(ProcessStage.GETTINGPRODUCTS);
 processRepo.saveAndFlush(setProcess);
```

**and this overwrites the changes saved to that database with the dropletRepo effectively undoing the changes previously save to the database.**

So I assume that because the DownloadDroplets have a relationship to Process and I'm saving process following saving the downloaddroplets that I'm having this problem.

How do I avoid this problem?

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have to merge the `Process` entity before you do the changes to it.

This will refresh the state with what was previously persisted to the context.

You already have the cascade merge due to `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on `@OneToMany` annotation so this will propagate to all the `DownloadDroplet` entities in the list.

Comment: I've removed the CascadeType.ALL from the entity declaration and now the system works as expected. It's seems like the cascade was causing the updates to DownloadDroplet to be overwritten. I'll look into how to merge appropriately in this instance.